# Malicious URI handling for connection with external websites

Tags: php, rest, api, security, uri

My application allows the user to connect to my backend from which it will redirect the request to an external api of another website.

This other website allows access to a REST API through the usage of an application and private key. The keys are stored in my backend server for security purposes. The other website allows other developers/administrators to make their own instance of that website with the same REST API keys but with different content.

**So the flow is as follows:**

1. Client application connects to backend server.
2. (When successfully authenticated) The client sends request for information to backend server.
3. Backend server forwards the request to a REST API instance of an external website.
4. REST API instance of the external website returns requested information to backend server.
5. Backend server returns requested information to client.

In the process of requesting the information, the client needs to specify to which external API the backend server should connect via a URI.

With security in mind I've noticed a big issue with my system: the user could send a URI of a "REST API" in his possession that actually captures all the data between the backend server and the bad "REST API". This way the bad URI could capture the secret REST API keys for malicious purposes.

How can I be sure that the URI the client provides to the backend server is a legitimate URI for an external REST API and not just a random, bad or malicious URI?

The only solution I've came up with is a database check for the legitimacy of a URI to cope with this issue.